# C# Picking a specific value from a response from server?

Tags: c#, json

How to pick only a specific value from a server response ?
Server is sending response in JSON format and I need only one specific value from the the entire response.

**My code :**

```
var exitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var url = new Uri("wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com");
            using (var client = new WebsocketClient(url))
            {
                client.ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                client.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info =>
                    Console.WriteLine($"Reconnection happened, type: {info.Type}"));
                client.MessageReceived.Subscribe(msg => Console.WriteLine($"Message received: {msg}"));
                client.Start();
                Task.Run(() => client.Send("{\"type\": \"subscribe\",\"product_ids\": [\"ETH-USD\"]," +
                    "\"channels\": [ \"level1\",\"heartbeat\",{\"name\": \"ticker\",\"product_ids\": [\"ETH-USD\"]}]}"));
                exitEvent.WaitOne();
            }
```

**Here is the JSON Response:**

```
Message received: {"type":"ticker","sequence":23072222086,"product_id":"ETH-USD","price":"4555.43","open_24h":"4582.28","volume_24h":"145928.12243540","low_24h":"4435","high_24h":"4637.39","volume_30d":"4882834.91966503","best_bid":"4555.43","best_ask":"4555.44","side":"sell","time":"2021-12-03T09:26:50.426810Z","trade_id":187917443,"last_size":"0.02365389"}
```

**How can one pick only one specific value from entire response , Let say I want to pick the "Price" Value only.**

Comment: You need to deserailize the JSON and then you can have easy access to the items from JSON.

Comment: is deserialization the the easiest way ? or is there any other easier alternatives as well ?
I am fairly new to c#  and still just getting my feet wet  thats why I am asking about the Easiest way

Answer (score 1):

If it is just to read one property the fastests way is to use Newtonsoft.Json.
So download above package and just use:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var parsedJObject = JObject.Parse(response);
var price = parsedJObject["price"];
```

Edit:

```
client.MessageReceived.Subscribe(MessageReceived);

void MessageReceived(string message)
{
   var parsedJObject = JObject.Parse(response);
   var price = parsedJObject["price"];
}
```

Comment: I tried it Like this `var parsedJObject = JObject.Parse(client.MessageReceived.Subscribe() );` but this is giving me error  `cannot convert from 'System.IDisposable' to 'string'`

Comment: You wanna parse your json message as you gave in an example. Check edited answer